# create dynamic component not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

create dynamically component below code but not rendering, its showing in empty elements.

**app.components.ts**

*my json:*

```
comp =[  
   {  
      "ty":"screen",
      "grids":[  
         {  
            "ty":"grid",
            "components":[  
               {  
                  "ty":"tb"
               },
               {  
                  "ty":"tb"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "ty":"grid",
            "components":[  
               {  
                  "ty":"bt"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Iterate the components from json**

```
ngOnInit() {
      // this.iterate(keys: any)
      var griditem;

      for(var i=0;i<this.comp[0].grids.length;i++)

      {
        if(this.comp[0].grids[i].ty=='grid'){
          griditem='<div> sample Grid';
              for(var j=0;j<this.comp[0].grids[i].components.length;j++)
              {
                if(this.comp[0].grids[i].components[j].ty=='tb'){
                  griditem = griditem +'<input matInput placeholder='Favorite food' value='Sushi'>';
                }else if(this.comp[0].grids[i].components[j].ty=='bt'){
                  griditem = griditem +'<div> sample Button'+j+' </div>';
                }
              }
              griditem= griditem +'</div>';              

        }
        this.renderedGrid = this.renderedGrid+griditem;
      }


}
```

**In app.components.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="renderedGrid"></div>
```

Above code not render input element, its rendering empty element, any missing in this code.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i tired create the component based on json response , above json  there is two grid is there, first grid two components and second grid is one compoonent. so first i find the whether grid available, if grid is there then draw the grid and checking any components, if components is there then i draw the component .

here matinput component not rendering, if i am using normal p tag then its rendered as a html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this whole approach seems like an anti-pattern for angular component system. But it sounds like the question really is: how to iterate a through a model to generate angular material components.

The answer is ngFor, ngIf, and here's an example with your current model

Without adding any code in typescript, other than the model

In HTML you can do the following

```
<div *ngFor="let component of comp">
  <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px" *ngFor="let grid of component.grids">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let gridComponent of grid.components">
      <div *ngIf="gridComponent.ty=='tb'">
        <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="gridComponent.ty=='bt'">
        <button md-button>Click me!</button>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

For each component, we can create a mat-grid-list using **ngFor**
For each grid-list, we can create a component using **ngFor**, inside of each component we can identify what kind of tag we want to add here using **ngIf**

[image]

Comment: great @lancovici, the sample its working fine. is it possible render component and inject into html page?. i mean, created separate input component and button component.

right now  input tag directly written so instead of direct html can inject from component wise

Answer (score 0):

[image]

like this created button component and input component

Comment: it Sounds like you’re trying to generate a web app that can reprogram itself. Is that true?

Comment: yes, initially app.component.html parent div only is there once construct all json value and then only render in dom  in particular screen, so first i have construct all values and keep it in one variable and placed in dom.

so i have json value in app.component.ts i have to construct the components based on json and put it in app.component.html any possible way is there doing this scenario

Comment: Generating html, with existing components, based on json is possible. 
What you mention here is generating components based on json, then to redraw html files with them, is not possible with just angular. Angular can only render stuff for you, it's really angular CLI that compiles it and packages it with webpack, then you manually deploy it. So what you're talking about sounds like:

Comment: 1. Read json file, 2. Generate Angular components. 3. Generate components html files based on new angular components. 4. Compile angular project. 5. Deploy angular project to replace current one running online. This all requires a back-end framework  and access to a local file system (like nodejs/express and some other packages). None of which a front-end framework like angular provides.

Comment: ok done, i understood.
i tried what you gave earlier just change above lines in app.component.html file


instead of direct input tag i just changed component selector its rendered and i trying this in through ts file itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let component of comp">
  <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px" *ngFor="let grid of component.grids">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let gridComponent of grid.components">
      <div *ngIf="gridComponent.ty=='tb'">
       <input-comp></input-comp>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="gridComponent.ty=='bt'">
       <button-comp></button-comp>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```